# What is stopping my form to be sumitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have made a form and i am validating it on client side using jquery. Validations are working well, but after validations, form is not submitted.Can somebody tell me what's wrong here?

Blur events are working fine..But form is not submitted.
The action attribute of form is pointing to the laravel function.

Form:-

```
  <form id="demo_form2" method="post" action="{{url('admin/manage/save_admin')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="name" required="required" name="name"><span id="namerror">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" required="required" ><span id="emailerror">
 <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required"><span id="passerror">
<input name="myfile"  type="file" id="file1" accept="image/*"><span id="imgerror">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var nm=$('#name').val();
      var em=$('#email').val();
      var ps=$('#password').val();
      var img=$('#file1').val();
       var nmreg=/^[A-Za-z ]{3,20}$/i;
       var emreg=/^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
       var psreg=/^[a-z0-9A-Z!@#$%^&*() <>{}()?/":']{6,30}$/i;
    $('#demo_form2').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();


       if(nmreg.test(nm)==false || nm.trim()=='' || nm==''){return false;}
else{return true;}
      if(emreg.test(em)==false || em.trim()=='' || em==''){return false;}
else{return true;}
      if(psreg.test(ps)==false || ps.trim()=='' || ps==''){return false;}
else{return true;}
      if(img=='' || img.trim()==''){return false;}
else{return true;}

    });

    $('#name').on('blur',function(){
       if(nmreg.test(nm)==false || nm.trim()=='' || nm=='')
       {
            $('#nameerror').html("Please Enter Valid Name");
          return false;
       }
       else
       {
          $('#nameerror').html("");
          return true;
       }
    });


    $('#email').on('blur',function(){
      if(emreg.test(em)==false || em.trim()=='' || em==''){  $('#emailerror').html("Please Enter Valid Email");
        return false;}
      else{  $('#emailerror').html("");
         return true;
      }
    });


    $('#password').on('blur',function(){
      if(psreg.test(ps)==false || ps.trim()=='' || ps=='')
      {
        $('#passerror').html("Enter Valid Password(6-30 characters)");
        return false;
      }
      else { $('#passerror').html("");
        return true; }
    });

    $('#file1').on('blur',function(){
   if(img==''){        $('#imgerror').html("Select an Image"); }
      else{   $('#imgerror').html("");
        return true; }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your form's `submit` event handler calls: `e.preventDefault();` as the very first thing that it does, so none of the other code will have any impact. You've cancelled the form's submit event.**

Remove that line and only use it when you know your form is not valid.

Instead of littering your code with `return true` and `return false`, assume that the form is valid and only when you're validation tests prove that it's not, cancel the `submit` event with the `event` argument that is automatically passed to your callback, like this `e.preventDefault()`.

Also (FYI), the `.html()` method is for setting/getting strings that contain HTML. If you aren't using HTML strings, use `.text()` instead. It's faster and more secure.